# How to make IntelliJ IDEA recognize the Grails database migration plugin's DSL?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, dsl, grails-plugin, liquibase

With the fabulous [db migration Grails plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/index.html), it is really easy to bundle [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) database migrations into a Grails project so that my schema can be versioned along with my application code and provides a nice, clean, *easily scriptable* upgrade / downgrade mechanism.

The only difficulty is that IntelliJ IDEA doesn't know anything about the DSL that the database migration plugin uses! I know IntelliJ IDEA [can deal with specialized DSLs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness) like this, but I can't seem to find a gDSL descriptor for the db migration plugin anywhere.

The majority of the DSL is directly from the Liquibase XML schema, with some extra Grails goodness added in so that you can run arbitrary Groovy code during the migration.

Does anyone know if there is a gDSL descriptor file for IntelliJ IDEA for the Grails database migration plugin, or where I might find one that someone else made or perhaps how I might go about making one myself?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly what you want, but what I do is write the liquibase-specific bits in a changelog XML file. This way I get the autcomplete facilities provided by the liquibase XML schema. This proves to be very smooth in intellij idea.

Then if you wish, there is a command: dbm-changelog-to-groovy that will convert your xml to groovy.

I, however, don't bother with that second step. I keep liquibase-related changes in xml files and custom groovy scripts in groovy files, for example complex data migration tasks, and I'm quite happy with that.

Comment: Yes, it's not quite what I'm after, but it's definitely a functional workaround for now. Unfortunately, most of my changes involve substantial groovy code because I'm taking a (very) legacy database and normalizing / upgrading it, so I really would like IntelliJ Idea to be able to work with the DSL.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ allows the [creation of plugins for custom languages](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA) which is what someone would need to do specifically for the liquibase DSL.